# Android Studio Pass data from a ListView to AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to pass data from a ListView to AlertDialog but I am unable to do so. I have a ListView with some items in each row, and I would like it to be such that when I click on any of them, the specific data in each row in the ListView will be passed to the AlertDialog.

Below is my array where I have declared some items that will show up in the ListView.

```
String devices[] = {"Phone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3", "Phone 4"};
```

Below is the code for the device names to appear in the listview.

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Names.length;
}

@Override

public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    TextView textView_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PhoneName);

    textView_name.setText(Titles[i]);
   

        return view;

}
}
```

Below is the OnClick for the AlertDialog to appear. showDeviceInfo() is a method that will display the AlertDialog.

```
 listViewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          
            showDeviceInfo();


        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

Below is the showDeviceInfo() method.

```
    public void showDeviceInfo(){

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_device, null);
    

    TextView DeviceName = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);

    alert.setView(mView);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    
    
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

I hope with someone's help, I will be able to display the specific device names inside the AlertDialog's TextView DeviceName when a specific row of the ListView is clicked on. I have done some research prior to asking but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user clicks on the row item just get the position and get the item from the list and pass it to the dialog to show in TextView or something. for ex.

get the device name in click listener like below.

```
listViewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //or showDeviceInfo(devices[position]);
            showDeviceInfo(Names[position]); //whatever array you have for devices just get the item based on position and pass it 
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

and pass it to the showing dialog function like below.

```
  public void showDeviceInfo(String name){
    
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_device, null);
        
    
        TextView DeviceName = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
        DeviceName.setText(name); //setting device name
        alert.setView(mView);
    
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        
        
        alertDialog.show();
    
    }
```